# Safely convert `float` to `double` without loss of precision

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

I have the following head scratcher, demonstrated in `jshell` `11.0.12` and `17.0.1` here

```
jshell> 13.9f
$1 ==> 13.9

jshell> 13.9
$2 ==> 13.9

jshell> (double) 13.9f
$3 ==> 13.899999618530273
```

The same thing occurs in a simple compiled class in both versions

```java
strictfp public class Test {

    public strictfp static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.format("%s%n", (double) 13.9f);
        System.out.format("%s%n", 13.9f);
    }

}
```

```
╰─➤  java Test      
13.899999618530273
13.9
```

Although 17 warns that `strictfp` is no longer required

```
warning: [strictfp] as of release 17, all floating-point expressions are evaluated strictly and 'strictfp' is not required
```

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/jls17.pdf) says this in section 5.1.2

```
A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the overall
magnitude of a numeric value in the following cases, where the numeric value is
preserved exactly:
• from an integral type to another integral type
• from byte, short, or char to a floating-point type
• from int to double
• from float to double
```

In 14 it contained the following after the bullet list

```
A widening primitive conversion from float to double that is not strictfp may
lose information about the overall magnitude of the converted value.
```

Based on my reading this is a bug in the implementation? The only reliable way I've found to perform this conversion is `Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(13.9f))`.

Comment: Floating point is just an approximation, a limited sum of powers of 2. A `float` is an even worse approximation than `double`, hence a cast to double will show the floats approximation errors. `strictfp` prevented the FPU (floating point processor) to use 10 bytes floating point instead of 8. More or less irrelevant to this question. Floating point does not have a precision, number of digits after decimal point.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon <- the difference between 13.9 and the number you are seeing is on the order of single precision epsilon, so the conversion f-to-d was most likely accurate, that's what the number was all along

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Based on my reading this is a bug in the implementation?

No. It's a bug in your expectations. The `double` value you're seeing is exactly the same value as the `float` value. The precise value is 13.8999996185302734375.

That's *not* the same as "the closest `double` value to 13.9" which is 13.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625.

You're assigning the value 13.8999996185302734375 to a `double` value, and then printing the string representation - which is 13.899999618530273 as that's enough precision to completely distinguish it from other `double` values. If it were to print 13.9, that *would* be a bug, as there's a `double` value that's closer to 13.9, namely 13.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625.